# How to use String.format in groovy?

Tags: groovy, string.format

The code below prints the `response` variable preceded by spaces.

The number of spaces to be printed before the `response` variable is equivalent to the difference of the `itemNumber` and the `examineeResponses`.

Now, is it possible to pad the string with zero (`"0"`) instead of spaces using String.format?

```
def converted = examineeResponses+String.format("%${itemNumber - 1}s", response)
```

Example using the above codes:

```
examineeResponses = '1' // String
itemNumber = 10 //int
response = '3' // String
```

Output:

```
"        3"
```

Desired output:

```
"000000003"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you can do this, but it's a bit hard to understand your question:

```
int itemNumber = 10
String examineeResponses = '1'
char response = '3'

"$response".padLeft( itemNumber - examineeResponses.length(), '0' )
```

Though I suspect (you don't say) that you just want it printed `itemNumbers` characters wide.  If this is the case, you just need:

```
"$response".padLeft( itemNumber, '0' )
```

And you don't need `examineeResponses` at all.

One of the bits I struggle with in your question is I don't know what `examineeResponses.length()` is supposed to do (other than throw an error).  Another is I'm not sure that this is what you want to do ;-)

You can't zero pad Strings with `String.format` in Java or Groovy, you can only zero pad numerics

Comment: the examineeResponses.length() refers to the length of the response variable. it is an integer..

Comment: `Integer.length()` is not a method.  What do you mean by length?

Comment: Do you mean the length of the String if you were to convert the integer to a String?  Like: `"${14}".length() == 2`?

Comment: examineeResponses is actually a string, and I am using length() to get  its size. thanks.

Comment: Ahhh, I was confused when you kept saying it was an `int` in your question...  Updated the padLeft line in my answer

Comment: In the above example I mean, String.format("%${9}s", response)

Comment: Yeah, I realise now.  You can't do that and use '0' to pad using String.format (see my answer)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17596/discussion-between-chemillex3-and-tim-yates)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
def formattedString = "blahblah.com?param=${param}&hash=${hash}"
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: It is what I was looking for though.